# Parsing log values with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a shell script to parse values from grepped lines of a log:

```
 <WhereIsTheCar - the car with id number 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111' is driving to: Canada>
 <WhereIsTheCar - the car with id number 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222' is driving to: Mexico>
 <WhereIsTheCar - no car could be found with the following ID number: 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333'>
```

I've already grepped for those lines and created an array.  I'm then looking to get an output that's something like:

```
Canada
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111

Mexico
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222

Not Found
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333
```

I'm admittedly not very good at shell scripting but I've figured out a somewhat 'brute force' approach to obtaining the values I want:

```
i=0
for line in "${grep[@]}"
do
    loc[i]=`sed -e "s/.*\:\(.*\)>/\1/" <<< $line | sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "s/^\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g"`
    echo ${loc[i]};
    id[i]=`sed -e "s/^.*\'\(.*\)\'.*$/\1/" <<< $line | sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//" -e "s/[ \t]*$//" -e "s/^\([\"']\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g"`
    echo ${id[i]};
    let i++
done
```

Where I'm creating a location and id array and then trying to trim off the whitespace and extra quotes.  I think I can finish from here but I was wondering if someone had a more elegant (or better suited) approach.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is just to use `BASH_REMATCH` in bash rather than `awk` or `sed`

```
   BASH_REMATCH
          An  array  variable  whose members are assigned by the =~ binary
          operator to the [[ conditional command.  The element with  index
          0  is  the  portion  of  the  string matching the entire regular
          expression.  The element with index n  is  the  portion  of  the
          string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.  This vari‐
          able is read-only.
```

So this should work for you

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ "is driving to:"(.*)">" ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} || echo "Not Found"
  [[ $line =~ \'(.*)\' ]] && echo -e "\t${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\n"
done < "file"
```

Example output

```
> ./abovescript
Canada
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111

Mexico
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222

Not Found
    Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333
```

Answer (score 1):

awk would make it easier:

```
awk -F"('|driving to: |>)" '{printf "%s\n\t%s\n\n", NF==5?$4:"Not Found",$2;next}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
<WhereIsTheCar - the car with id number 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111' is driving to: Canada>
<WhereIsTheCar - the car with id number 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222' is driving to: Mexico>
<WhereIsTheCar - no car could be found with the following ID number: 'Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333'>

kent$  awk -F"('|driving to: |>)" '{printf "%s\n\t%s\n\n", NF==5?$4:"Not Found",$2;next}' f
Canada
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111

Mexico
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222

Not Found
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -nr "/driving to/ s/.*'([^']+)'.*:(.*)>/\2\n\t\1/p; /no car could be found/ s/.*'([^']+)'.*/ Not Found\n\t\1/p" file

 Canada
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 1111
 Mexico
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 2222
 Not Found
        Sys Generated. VARIABLESTRING 3333
```

Explanation:

Split to two parts, and work on input file directly, no need for loop.

Hints: use double quota when need handle single quota in sed.

`/driving to/ s/.*'([^']+)'.*:(.*)>/\2\n\t\1/p` used to take the content that car is found
`/no car could be found/ s/.*'([^']+)'.*/ Not Found\n\t\1/p` used to take the content that  no car is found.